# Laravel custom collection or custom query builder?

Tags: php, laravel

I have that project that have orders that have status, and every status can be seen depending on if the user have the permission to manage it. I've tried to use custom collection but the downside is it's not paginatiable by default,
here's the code

```php
class OrdersCollection extends Collection
{
    public function allowedForUser(User $user)
    {
        return $this->filter(function ($order) use ($user) {
            return $user->can(sprintf('manage %s orders', strtolower($order->status)));
        });
    }
}
```

here's how I'm trying to use it

```php
$orders = Order::withoutTrashed()
            ->allowedForUser(Auth::user())
            ->paginate(50);
```

EDIT:

to avoid filtering through 20k+ rows in the table I came up with this custom builder

```php
class OrderBuilder extends Builder
{
    public function WhereAllowedForUser(User $user)
    {
        $permissions = $user->permissions()
            ->where('name', 'like', 'manage % orders')
            ->pluck('name')
            ->map(function ($item) {
                return str_replace('manage ', '', str_replace(' orders', '', $item));
            });

        return $this->whereIn('status', $permissions);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the problem ? That it is not paginatable ?

Comment: yes, It's not paginatable, If I used the above code to paginate I get ``Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::allowedForUser()``

Comment: Yeah, that is because you are still in `Builder` and is not a collection. I think a good approach would be to create a scoped query and pass the data you need to then filter (on DB) with what you need.

Comment: any code sample I could work with? I tried to pluck the permission names and then use whereIn, but the permission for example called 'manage rejected orders', the order status is rejected.I couldn't find a clean way of doing it.

Comment: Order is a model, why should extend an collection when you can put allowedForUser in the model class? then filter the get() value

Comment: @Jerson the orders table have 20k orders right now and it might get larger, every time this happens will get all the 20k rows and filters through them.

Comment: maybe you can try to collect() the returned value and only then to paginate it.

Comment: @GonrasKarols that is not recommended as it will take forever and maybe even run out of memory, filter must be done on DB and then paginate results on DB too

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`scoped queries`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) for your Model.

The idea is for you to pass a value to the scope and do what you want/need with it:

```php
class Order extends Model
{
    public function scopeWhereAllowedForUser($query, User $user)
    {
        $permissions = $user->permissions()
            ->where('name', 'like', 'manage % orders')
            ->pluck('name')
            ->map(function ($item) {
                return str_replace('manage ', '', str_replace(' orders', '', $item));
            });

        return $query->whereIn('status', $permissions);
    }
}
```

So you use it like this:

```php
$orders = Order::whereAllowedForUser(Auth::user())->paginate(50);
```

---

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do with that `$permissions` query, I am not sure what you tried to do, so explain it a little more and I can help you with it (better code).

Comment: I'm using spatie/laravel-permission, every user has a set of permissions. some of them can manage orders depending on the order status, a user can have permissions to edit rejected and accepted orders so he would have "manage rejected orders" and "manage accepted orders". I want to show allowed orders to be managed by this user which is "rejected and accepted"statuses

Comment: Bro, u just copy and pasted the code in the question, and yes it works.

Comment: Laravel supports custom builders, you can use it in your model like this: public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
    return new Builder($query);
}

Comment: Here's a guide if you want to read about it https://medium.com/@channingdefoe/adding-custom-builder-and-collection-methods-to-laravel-models-a72ab6ec0dc6

Comment: Why use a custom builder when you can use a scoped query ? It is not even in the official documentation... you are using non standard code... be careful with that...

Comment: Bro, it is standard Laravel code, I like to scale down the functions on the model by sperating the model and the business logic, that way I wouldn't have a single file doing everything and becomes cluttered.also It is standard Laravel code.